# Converting numbers within grid to their corresponding x,y coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, grid

Given the numbers in the following grid (from 1 to 36), how can I determine their coordinates (x,y) within the grid?

```
 |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
------------------------------
0|  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1| 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
2| 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
3| 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

i.e. what I want to obtain is the following:

```
 |     0     1     2        8
------------------------------
0| (0,0) (1,0) (2,0) ... (8,0)
1| (0,1) (1,1) (2,1) ... (8,1)
2| (0,2) (1,2) (2,2) ... (8,2)
3| (0,3) (1,3) (2,3) ... (8,3)
```

I have tried:

```
x = number%9-1;
y = number/9;
```

which works for all cases except the ones in the last column on the right.

So I came up with:

```
if (number%9==0) {
    x = 8;
    y = number/9-1;
}
else{
    x = number%9-1;
    y = number/9;
}
```

My  question is, is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x = (number-1)%9;
y = (number-1)/9;
```

Comment: Thiton beat me by a few seconds so deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

If instead your numbering system goes from from 0 to 35 instead, it's thiton's answer but omit the "-1". So that's:

```
x = (number)%9;
y = (number)/9;
```