# Coordinates to Grid Box Number

Tags: math, grid, coordinates

Let's say I have some grid that looks like this

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|     |     |     |
|  0  |  1  |  2  |
|_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _| 
|     |     |     |
|  3  |  4  |  5  |
|_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _| 
|     |     |     |
|  6  |  7  |  8  |
|_ _ _|_ _ _|_ _ _|
```

How do I find which cell I am in if I only know the coordinates? For example, how do I get `0` from `(0,0)`, or how do I get `7` from `(1,2)`?

Also, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669189/converting-numbers-within-grid-to-their-corresponding-x-y-coordinates), which does what I want to do in reverse, but I can't reverse it for my needs because as far as I know there is not a mathematical inverse to modulus.

Comment: Shouldn't (1,2) map to 5 ? (considering your co-ordinate system is centered at 0 and increments down and right)

Comment: @Amit: He is writing `(x,y)` rather than `(y,x)`.  I understand your confusion though:  in both matricies and computer-graphics, which count `(0,0)` as the upper-left element, the coordinates are written as `(y,x)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, given cell index `A` in the range [0, 9), the row is given by `R = floor(A/3)` and the column is given by `C = A mod 3`.

In the general case, where `MN` cells are arranged into a grid with `M` rows and `N` columns (an `M x N` grid), given a whole number B in [0, MN), the row is found by `R = floor(B/N)` and the column is found by `C = B mod N`.

Going the other way, if you are given a grid element (R, C) where R is in [0, M) and C is in [0, N), finding the element in the scheme you show is given by `A = RN + C`.

Answer (score 5):

```
cell = x + y*width
```

Programmers use this often to treat a 1D-array like a 2D-array.

Answer (score 0):

#### For future programmers

May this be useful:

```js
let wide = 4;
let tall = 3;
let reso = ( wide * tall);

for (let indx=0; indx<reso; indx++)
{
    let y = Math.floor(indx/wide);
    let x = (indx % wide);
    console.log(indx, `x:${x}`, `y:${y}`);
};
```